# Dark colours strobing on external display plugged in via HDMI with MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I've noticed that my screen was slightly strobing when my MacBook is plugged in via HDMI to my LG TV. The issue does not repro when there's lighter colours, and it also doesn't repro on the Mac's internal panel.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/805459/mac-flickering-external-screen/), it turns out that it was because I'd configured the external display to use Variable Refresh Rate. Disabling this has fixed the issue for me.